# HTACCESS - Change Directory Structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I recently changed our URL structure for several different pages but I'm having some trouble with the HTACCESS rewrites. I've included the examples below and I'm hoping that someone can help me with the correct rule to use!

```
http://www.tintworld.com/ny/albany-022/home-window-tinting/ <-- Original URL
http://www.tintworld.com/albany-ny-022/home-window-tinting/ <-- New URL ('ny' is moved)
```

I'm currently trying to use the following rule but it's not redirecting the original URLs...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.tintworld\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^ny/albany-022/$ http://www.tintworld.com/albany-ny-022? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Please help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due matching `^ny/albany-022/$` in your `RewriteRule`.  The `$` in regular expressions denotes the end of the line.  Try removing the `$`, and adding the remaining part onto the rewritten URL

```
RewriteRule ^ny/albany-022/(.*) http://www.tintworld.com/albany-ny-022/$1
```

The `$1` here puts in the part that's matched by the `(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have several different pages, I would recommend using a plugin like

http://www.weberz.com/plugins/404-redirected/

to keep track of 404 pages and redirect them